# How to throw internal server error without hitting .NET Core backend?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How can I throw an internal server error with out hitting the .NET Core backend ?

Regards,

Comment: `return new StatusCodeResult(500);` maybe? What code do you have so far? What is the "backend" that you want to avoid?

Comment: Does `throw new Exception("This is a custome exception");` answers your question?

Comment: What do you mean by "with out hitting the .net core backend"? It looks like you want to simulate a 500 internal error on client side. Its a bit confusing for me. If this is what you really want to do I think you can try to mock the response. There should be plenty of libs to help you with that. 
However, If you want to force a 500 error on the backend side just throw an exception like the other already answered here.

Comment: eturn new StatusCodeResult(500) worked. thanks